# Error generating chart: User memory limit exceeded, when changing dataset from T1_TOA to T1_SR

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, memory

So, I got the code to work for T1_TOA band, but then when I switched it over to T1_SR band it gave me this error: User memory limit exceeded.
So, I poked around the forum and found the code to limit my date frames, but I still get the error.
Not quite sure what I'm missing.

```
// Import the Landsat 8 SR image collecton.

Map.addLayer(study_area, {color: 'Black'}, "study_area");

function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}

var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterBounds(study_area)
                  .map(maskL8sr)
                  .select('B5' , 'B4');
print(dataset);

var startDate = ee.Date('2013-05-01'); // set analysis start time
var endDate = ee.Date('2013-9-30'); // set analysis end time


// 'Reduce' stack of images by using the median value for each pixel and clip to study area
var output_bands = dataset.reduce(ee.Reducer.median()).clip(study_area);
print(output_bands)
// 
var index = output_bands.normalizedDifference(['B5_median', 'B4_median']); // NDVI calculated using NIR and red bands
print(index); // DISPLAY metadata

// DISPLAY output band
Map.addLayer(index, {}, 'NDVI');



print(ui.Chart.image.series({
  imageCollection: index,
  region: study_area,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.median(),
  scale: 30
}).setOptions({title: 'Cloud-masked NDVI over time'}));
```

Comment: Could you upload the full script via a link or provide the ```study_area``` variable. Without it, it's hard to know what causes an issue for you.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fbrianwhitmancd%2FImagery%3ABriansLandsat8%2Flandsat8%20alkaliwatershed%202013%20NDVI%20chart%20v3%20T1_SR

Comment: Let me know if the link doesn't work

Comment: The link doesn't work. The repository "users/brianwhitmancd/Imagery"  does not exists, maybe you have moved the script or saved it in another repository.

Comment: I'm not sure how to share the shapefile, but it's a watershed that is about 30,000 acres (121 km2).

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/brianwhitmancd/penawawa

Comment: Okay, try the link to the shared variable

Answer (score 2):

From looking at your code I see you haven't specified the time for your `dataset`. You defined the `startDate`and `endDate`, but haven't applied them in the collection.

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR')
                  .filterBounds(study_area)
                  .filterDate('2013-05-01','2013-09-30')
                  .map(maskL8sr)
                  .select('B5' , 'B4');
print(dataset);
```

Notice that I removed the `startDate` and `endDate` variables and instead specified the time interval in the imagecollection using `filterDate()`.

It's important to keep in mind that when you switch from one dataset to another (in this case Landsat 8 TOA to Landsat 8 SR), you might have different amount images. That's why filtering for your specific needs is important to carry out correctly.

Comment: So, putting in the filter date gave me an error stating no features contain non-null values of "system:time_start". I tried changing date and a few other ideas I got from poking around, but can't seem to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

To answer to your comment, "system:time_start" error appears because after running the cloud mask, your dataset loses the metadata info. Try using `.copyProperties()` command in the cloudmask function like so:

```
function maskL8sr(image) {
  // Bits 3 and 5 are cloud shadow and cloud, respectively.
  var cloudShadowBitMask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudsBitMask = (1 << 5);
  // Get the pixel QA band.
  var qa = image.select('pixel_qa');
  // Both flags should be set to zero, indicating clear conditions.
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitMask).eq(0)
                 .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudsBitMask).eq(0));
  return image.updateMask(mask).copyProperties(image,['system:time_start']);
}
```

Comment: Same message again. Dang, did you get it to work on your end? I tried it a couple different ways and couldn't get it. The NDVI image shows up, it's just the chart doesn't...